# "Where is pick-up" or "where is the pick-up"?

Tags: articles

Would you tell me if I have to use *the* before *pick-up* in the context below?

> We can deliver the load in time. Where is (**the**) pick up?

Is the use of *the* there optional?

Comment: *Most* native speakers would probably include the article in your exact context, but at least *some* people will feel that it's perfectly grammatical without. And I'm in the second category there - so far as I'm concerned, the cited usage is on a par with asking ***What time is** [the] **kick-off**?* (When does the football match start?). Where my guess is that *most* native speakers don't include the article, but it's fine either way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'd be happy with 'kick off' but for some unquantifiable reason I can't see pick up without 'the'.

Comment: I agree with @gonefishin'again. 'kick-off' sounds OK, but saying 'Where is pick up' sounds extremely unnatural to me. I'd say the article is necessary in this case.

Comment: @gonefishin'again.: I expect the "unquantifiable reason" is mostly that you haven't encountered the usage *personally* much if at all. But if you'd been working as a deliveryman for years you probably *would* be more likely to discard the article, simply because you'd be saying and hearing things like OP's example so often. And if you added it up, that would probably equate to saying that over a lifetime in the delivery business, do you want to spend several hours in total enunciating the completely optional article? (I'd rather save all that time up, and get myself a whole afternoon off! :)

Comment: Are you guys *sure* it's the actual word ***pick-up*** that's making you balk? I accept that ***Where's pick-up**?* doesn't roll off the tongue quite so easily as ***When's kick-off**?* But I have absolutely no qualms about ***When's pick-up**?*, and I really can't bring myself to say the rules are different for ***When's*** and ***Where's***, so I'm gonna dig my heels in and say they're all fine - it just that (with apologies to Orwell in *Animal Farm* :) ***some contexts are more fine than others***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I've been in jobs where pick-ups would happen frequently, though I've avoided football since I can remember. I really don't know *why* one sounds right, the other wrong.

Comment: I think what's going on here is the same thing that makes, say, Apple's advertising copy writers seek to promote article-less usages such as ***You're never alone with iPhone X*** (it's ***so*** familiar to the speaker / writer that it doesn't ***need*** an article). Discarding the article somehow "elevates" the status of the referent. So if *[the] **kickoff** [time]* or *[the] **pickup** [point]* are important to you and the people you often speak with, you'll soon get into the habit of discarding those unnecessary words in brackets. But not otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence:

> "**We can deliver the load in time. Where is the pick up?**"

I personally insist that the word "the" is crucial to include if you want this to sound good to the ears of most native speakers of English. Personally I would say "**where is the pick-up spot**" or "**where would you like to collect the delivery"** to avoid using the two-word noun "pick up", but if for some reason you only wanted to write it in one of the two ways you suggested, it's better to include the word "the". As a native speaker of English, I cringe a little bit when people leave out *article* words like "the" and "a", because it reminds me of other similar sentences like "I go to bus" instead of "I go to the bus" (the former version being used almost exclusively by people who have no yet gone very far in their learning of the English language).